# Difficulty in connecting to wifi on my Ubuntu 14.04. HP-pavalion g6

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ath9k

I am not able to connect to wireless network on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I reinstalled the OS but still getting the same problem. I went through certain post and ran wireless-info.txt on my machine the result of whic is as follows. Please help me resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16321584/

Comment: See if things improve after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the network you want to connect to is (you didn't specify, but it is the loudest):

```
Wireless Access Points 
MyHP_Network:    Infra, <MAC 'MyHP_Network' [AC1]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 90 WPA WPA2
```

You can follow the [tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/setup-wireless-interface-with-wpa-and-wpa2-on-ubuntu) on `linuxconfig.org`.